# how to set a route using @input

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a component that uses a html attribute. I designed it so that an user can set the route when using that component in another component. But whenever I try to set the route value, I am running into a 'No provider for Router'.

This the output I get on the browser:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterLinkActive -> Router]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkActive -> Router]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

Here is the component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'li[o-nav-link]',
  template: `
    <a #link [routerLink]="route" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active"
     [attr.title]="title === 'undefined' ? null : title"
     [attr.aria-current]="isActive"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
  `
})

    export class ONavLink implements DoCheck {
      @HostBinding('class.nav-item')

      @Input()
      public route: string;

      @Input()
      public title: string;

      @ViewChild('link')
      public link: ElementRef;

      public isActive = false;

      public ngDoCheck() {
        this.isActive = this.link.nativeElement.classList.contains('active');
      }
    }
```

And i am using it like this:

```
<li o-nav-link route="test">Getting tested</li>
```

If you have any idea what is really going on right here, that could really help. I am futzing around like crazy !

and this is my module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgBoostedModule } from 'ng-boosted';

const approutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'start', component: AppComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    NgBoostedModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(approutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

PS: 'test' is defined in a route array :)

Comment: That error implies you need to import the `RouterModule` in your `AppModule`

Comment: @user184994 already did :).
I even re-read the tutorial on angular. everything is set up properly based on the tutorial :)

Comment: Can you add your module to the question please?

Comment: yep, did. @user184994

Comment: Which module is `ONavLink` declared in?

Comment: It declared in ngboostedModule, which is another angular project, I used npm link to link that. [ng boosted](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/Orange-Boosted-Angular/blob/version_3.3.0/src/o-navbar/o-navbar.component.ts) check this right here

Answer (score 0):

Import `RouterMoudle` in your `AppModule` and `[routerLink]` is an array of string not just a string value

Try to bind the `route` property as an array of string

`<li o-nav-link [route]="['test']">Getting tested</li>`

I think the above code will work - please check - happy coding !!

**Update:**

After some research i have changed the selector in the `ONavLink` component which was the major cause of the issue - In your question you are binding `[route]` which is not the known property of `<li>` and that's the triumph card of the issue

So finally here is the update -

**ONavLink.compoent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'li-link',
  template: `
    <a #link [routerLink]="route" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive='active'
     [attr.title]="title === 'undefined' ? null : title"
     [attr.aria-current]="isActive"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
  `
})
export class ONavLink implements DoCheck {
  @HostBinding('class.nav-item')

  @Input()
  public route: string[];

  @Input()
  public title: string;

  @ViewChild('link')
  public link: ElementRef;

  public isActive = false;

  public ngDoCheck() {
    this.isActive = this.link.nativeElement.classList.contains('active');
  }
}
```

I have changed the selector as `li-link` and the `route` property as `string[]` and you can access the component like this

`<li-link [route]="['test']">Getting Tested</li-link>`

Make sure you have the route `test` in your routes and make sure you are importing the modules

Hope this will work

Comment: Is there any error !! can you please share the source so that i can have a look - actually i have changed your `li` a bit `[route]="['test']"` but you have `linkto` which is not an property in the child component - please check that too

Comment: yes i did change it and set it was before. here is the [link to the project](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/Orange-Boosted-Angular/blob/version_3.3.0/src/o-navbar/o-navbar.component.ts).

Comment: I guess you tested it. But with the changes you made it's still rising the same error. something have change with router link but i don't know what so far...

Comment: Yeah i tested it twice - it was working fine for me - check the `href` by inspecting in the browser - I checked it shows `href= '/test'`

Comment: ok. There is something that I did wrong.
can you push your test ?

Comment: Yeah i will show you by tomorrow morning now I'm off work

Comment: Please check this link - [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjpzy5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Tanks Rahul !
Yeah it's working. I think I am doing something badly on my project.

Comment: Just try out the same way - it might work - happy coding - make sure to mark the answer - thanks

Comment: It will be great - if my solution worked just mark the answer - thanks

Comment: You solution is great ! And I figure out that my problem is coming from angular. My project was based on angular 5.2.9 and I upgraded it to 6.0.0. By investigating I find out there is a change made between the 6.beta 2 and 6 beta 3. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does my solution work ? yep angular dependency are something complex :) use the latest version of it always :)  - please do mark the answer if it works - Thanks